# Have to move screen to get JTextArea to appear

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, jscrollpane

I have a desktop pane program where a user inputs data and a jtextarea appears with their results. Instead of having just the text area, i wanted to add it to a scroll pane, which i did. So I created a new scroll pane, and added the text area to it. Now, when I put in data the text area in the scroll pane does not appear until I move the page. In other words, everything works, but I have to move the page a little in order for the results and the scroll pane to show up on the screen.

Any ideas on why this is happening?

```
 private JTextArea matchListResults = new JTextArea();
 private JPanel matchPanelBase = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
 private JScrollPane mResults = new JScrollPane();

    private void matchResFrame(String[] matchResultArray) throws IOException,          SQLException {

        Dimension size = new Dimension();
        size.setSize(400, 300);
        matchListResults.setPreferredSize(size);
        matchListResults.setFont(font);
```

.
.
.

```
        mResults.getViewport().add(matchListResults);
        matchListResults.setVisible(true);
        matchPanelBase.add(mResults, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add components to a visible GUI the basic code is:

```
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

By default all components have a size of (0, 0) so there is nothing to paint. The revalidate() will invoke the layout manager which will determine the components size and location.

Comment: I'll vote this one up as soon as it let's me. You're right though. After the panel was all set up, I had to revalidate and then repaint. repaint doesn't work by itself. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

After you add the new components, call repaint() on the panel.

```
matchPanelBase.repaint();
```